# refresh captcha displayed in image tag wp8 xaml

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am displaying captcha from a url in xaml like this

```
<Image Name="captcha" Source="http://lenovo-pc/vitforums/captcha.php" Margin="108,146,80,262"></Image>
```

where the source is a php script on another local computer on the lan ..
what I want to do I refresh the captcha image from the url when I click the refresh button .. how can I do that 
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"?

Comment: its like everytime i refresh the php page in the browser it fetches a new captcha image and displays it .. i want the same thing here such that when i refresh it fetches a new image from the php script ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reset the source to a new `URI` which is unique each time, for example by adding the current time as a querystring parameter like this:

```cs
private void Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    captcha.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://lenovo-pc/vitforums/captcha.php?t=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks, UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

Comment: to add this new parameter  do i have to make some change in the php code ?? .. if yes then what ..

Comment: thanks it works now :) .. but can u tell me why did i have to do this

Comment: Great, please mark this as answer then :) You have to do this because when you set the URL it first checks if it has a cached version of the image and in that case use that one, therefor giving the same image as the first time. But by adding the current time stamp the URL will be unique and therefore no cached image will be found.